# Your app asks for read and write permissions at the same time | attention20 July

Tags: facebook

i have a problem with my APP on facebook ...

Your app asks for read and write permissions at the same time. You should only ask for write permissions when a user tries to share something to Facebook. Please update your app accordingly. Read our best practices for more details.

Because of this problem, stop the publication on the wall a lot of the participants in the application

what should i do to fix it ?

Answer (score 3):

You should read their best practices and request write permissions **only** at the moment when you need it.

> People expect Facebook Login to be a fast process. As a best practice, you should not ask people for write permissions immediately after they agree to read permissions. Doing so results in two fast app switches which is a bad user experience. Instead, ask for write permissions at the most relevant time and explain to people why they should grant it. To learn more, see our documentation on publishing permissions.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/checklist/#avoidbacktoback

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand anything!!
But Is there a relationship  app Permissions ?

if yes , what i should pot in :
User & Friend Permissions:
and 
Extended Permissions:

and what about Auth Token Parameter:

Comment: @elsisi that's not where you ask for permissions. That's for the App Center. Check your code.

Comment: ok , what should i do to fix my problem ?

Comment: As phwd said, check your code.